# SQL grouping with multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

There's a table that I use that lists invoice detail. So for instance let's say a customer checks out with 2 items, there are 2 rows for each item.

Right now my SQL Query looks like this:

```
Select date
,order_id
,count(distinct(item_name))
from Table_1
group by 1,2
```

Rather than grouping it by order_id. Is there anyway to modify this query to find the number of Orders that have X amount of items on a specific date. So on 1/1/1990 5 orders have 3 items, 6 orders have 2 items, etc.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look into `having` if the answer below isn't what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could use a `subquery` grouping by the item count:

```
select t.date, t.itemCount, t.count(order_id)
from (
   Select date
       ,order_id
       ,count(distinct(item_name)) AS itemCount
   from Table_1
   group by 1,2
) AS t
group by date, itemCount
```